# Removing Item from an array in a dictionary at a given index path with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to work out how you remove an item form an array that is part of a dictionary.

I have a table view that takes an array from an object (PFObject from Parse) and I now want to know how to remove just one item from the array at the given index path.

I want to delete the item within the
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {` method for the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work in the end (I think my issue might have been something to do with the previous version of the Xcode beta i was running.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            let object: PFObject = self.array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
            object.deleteInBackground()
            array?.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this?

```
array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: No that's not quite enough to solve my issue I don't think. I have an object (a PFObject from Parse) that has (amongst other things) an array which holds several strings. This array is used to populate the text fields in a uitableview. I want to be able to delete the item in the cell (remove it from the array) and update the array.

Answer (score 0):

For array properties in a parse object, use the array accessors provided in the API, to remove, for example, see [`removeObject:forKey:` here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/removeObject:forKey:).

Notice that the remove method takes an object -- not an index path -- and a key.  They key is the property name of the array property.  If you start with only the index path, just address the array property with that index path to get the object.

**EDIT** For example, let's say the property is called `"arrayKey"`, and you have just an index path called `indexPath` (swift isn't my language, but...):

```
let array = myParseObject["arrayKey"] as [String]
let object = array[indexPath.row] as String
object.removeObject(object, forKey:"arrayKey")
```

Comment: I really don't understand this. I tried looking through all the docs but it is all obj-c not swift so i'm not confident that i'd ever get what I wanted from it.

Comment: You say the remove method takes an object not an index path. what does that mean? What object does it take? The key is the property name of the array property...could you give an example

Comment: @Elliot - did my best to provide swift example.  Since your question provides none of your code, my example makes quite a few guesses about the context in which you'd use it.

Comment: Awesome! Let me have a play around with that and see if I can get it working! I'll share some code if I'm struggling. I always feel like sharing the code will put people off answering as its a lot to read through when I think its a simple problem for someone else but I guess its only going to help others work out what i'm doing wrong! I really hope the parse docs get a big swift update soon!

Comment: Sorry, got set back massively after updating Xcode (latest beta) and everything failing to build and i've just got back to this part!

Comment: 'object["MyAttributeName"]?.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)'
  did if for me in the end. Not sure what the problem was but i'm confident this wasn't working for me in the last setup.